# type mismatch between indexed read

Tags: javabeans

Given these 2 classes:

BeanTestA.java

```java
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class BeanTestA<E>
{

  protected final List<E> list = new LinkedList<>();

  public abstract E getDelegateAt( int idx );

  public void setDelegateAt( int idx, E e )
  {
    list.set( idx, e );
  }

  public void removeDelegateAt( int idx )
  {
    list.remove( idx );
  }

}
```

BeanTestB.java:

```java
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class BeanTest
  extends BeanTestA<LinkedList>
{

  @Override
  public LinkedList getDelegateAt( int idx )
  {
    return list.get( idx );
  }

  @Override
  public void setDelegateAt( int idx, LinkedList v )
  {
    super.setDelegateAt( idx, v );
  }

  @Override
  public void removeDelegateAt( final int idx )
  {
    super.removeDelegateAt( idx );
  }


}
```

If I run:

```java
java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo( BeanTest.class );
```

I get an error:

```
java.beans.IntrospectionException: type mismatch between indexed read and indexed write methods: delegateAt
```

because at some point it calls java.beans.IndexedPropertyDescriptor.findIndexedPropertyType(Method,Method) with arguments of BeanTest.getDelegateAt and BeanTestA.setDelegateAt. findIndexedPropertyType gets indexedPropertyType from the return type of BeanTest.getDelegateAt, which is Object because of erasure. But then it gets LinkedList as the parameter, and throws IntrospectionException.

Is this a bug in java.beans.Introspector, or is this pattern of indexed beans with generics not supported?

This is with OpenJDK 1.7.0_25 (from Debian sid) and Oracle JDK 1.7.0_45 (from oracle.com).